# References in a 1934 German book

Tags: meaning

What do the dimunitions *aprov*., *afrz*., and *nprov*. refer to?

Comment: Did you search for those abbreviations with a search engine of your choice? If so, can you describe what is still unclear to you with those terms?

Comment: Give us some context. Was it a cookbook? Was it a novel? Please quote the sentences where you found those abbreviations.

Comment: Not a cookbook. Linguistics. @HubertSchölnast

Comment: @tallistroan: please [do not send people away to search engines](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1429/are-comments-requesting-a-google-search-welcome). Google is **nothing** without the content that sites like us provide.

Comment: [This is what Google says](https://www.google.com/search?q=aprov+afrz++nprov+german) - alas the site that comes top in the search results does not provide an answer.

Comment: @Takkat If you are looking up the abbreviations separately, the first hits are the correct answer on each term.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach: no doubt that we could find these abbreviations more or less easily (`nprov` still is not found) but that is not the point I made. It is German Language SE that comes first if someone searches for all three terms. We should at least provide an answer for those people coming from Google.

Comment: @Takkat it likely comes first because of this very question.

Comment: @Chieron Well, but this is an argument in favor of Takkat's point, because than the question should be answered here.

Comment: BTW, these kind of books tend to have a glossary where they explain their abbreviations

Comment: BTW if you, the community do not like the question there is not much to do: leave it downvoted and unanswered, close vote it again. The system will eventually auto-delete it after a while.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach No. The triple occurance will be so rare that it is not worth it. Takkat and the people clicking on his link will be the only ones looking at that google result page.

Comment: @Chieron: both wrong... Those books often have no glossary, and Google hits are a major source for traffic on all SE site including us. If you search for `nprov` you will have no luck at all, hence a combination with `aprov` or `afrz` is not unlikely if somebody needs to know their meaning.

Comment: @Takkat I totally see your points. However, on the other hand we usually expect at least a basic level of research before asking a question here, since we are not a basic translation service/dictionary. And in spite of good intentions, I can't see any upfront research in this question (and this was the reason for my comment). As also other commenters showed, at least the full words for *aprov* and *afrz* are easily findable with a Google search, and if OP had mentioned, that they were not able to find the meaning of *nprov* while providing the context, it would be a total valid question to me.

Comment: @tallistroan: fair enough. Of course we are free to expect a little or even a lot of effort from the OP before we take our time to answer - I can see this in this case too. But it may be that you found the answer quickly but this may not be with all search engines and definitely not in all countries. Would you have known the answer if you had no access to Google? Would you be happier if the OP had said: *I looked everywhere in Duden, Google, DuckDuckGo, Bing, and Wikipedia but did not find any explanation, now I came to you as my last resort.*?

Answer (score 2):

*From comments:*

For the languages/dialects altprovenzalisch, altfranzösisch, neuprovenzalisch. – Janka

Altprovenzalisch; Altfranzösisch; Neuprovenzalisch. – fdb